# How To Save a PPTX File with VBA

Tags: vba, save, powerpoint

So I'm making a powerpoint game, and I want there to be a save feature. I remember seeing a save function while browsing through the commands but I don't remember what to do. Does anyone know how to save a powerpoint file with a simple line of code? it can't be that complicated.

Comment: I'm not sure why you don't just browse through the commands again -
 the `Save` method is listed in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/presentation-save-method-powerpoint) and provides an example.

Answer (score 0):

You want the `Save` method of the presentation object:

```
Application.ActivePresentation.Save
```

You can find methods using the search box in the Object Browser:

[image]

Comment: Or if your fingers are tired:  ActivePresentation.Save.  The Application object is implicit.  ActivePresentation.SaveAs will save the current file to a new name and make the new file active.  Or ActivePresentation.SaveCopyAs will save a copy of the presentation to a new file name but won't make it the new active presentation.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Actually, `Application` isn't implicit per se, but `ActivePresentation` is a member of the hidden `Global` object, so yes, you can save yourself some typing, but using the qualified `Application` object is clearer, imo.

Comment: I only meant "implicit" in the sense that it's not necessary to specify it explicitly; your explanation is, of course, correct.  Thanks for the added clarity.

Comment: how can I make a Directory